# Local Contractibility of Homeomorphism Group of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, geometric-topology

For this question, let $X = \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $Aut(X)$ be the group of self-homeomorphisms with the compact-open topology.

Then I know that $Aut(X)$ is both locally path-connected, and locally contractible.  I have a decent sense of the implications of local path-connectedness: Two homeomorphisms which are sufficiently close in the compact-open topology can be joined by an isotopy of $X$.

But I don't have a good sense of what local contractibility means for this group.  I've read that spaces very similar to $X$, for example Euclidean Neighborhood Retracts, don't necessarily have locally contractible homeomorphism groups.  Why would that be?

> What's the geometric interpretation of local contractibility for these
> spaces?  How do you use it?

Thanks!  Sorry it's a bit of a 'soft question.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388706/do-locally-contractible-path-connected-groups-have-accessible-bases/388966?noredirect=1#comment990788_388966

Ok, it turns out that $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is locally contractible in the strong sense after all.  Y'all were making me so paranoid!  But it was a fun reference-hunt and makes me want to go back and study some of that old school retract theory stuff, I always tried to avoid it.

As per the answer in the MO thread, the space is locally homeomorphic to separable Hilbert space, so it satisfies everything you could ever want.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Černavskiĭ](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1969v008n03ABEH001121), the local contractibility of $Homeo(M)$ for a noncompact topological manifold $M$ implies that $M$ could be the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. Of course this is true when $M=\mathbb{R}^n$. For a statement see p.8, Th.2, of his paper

A. Černavskiĭ, *Local Contractibility of the Group of Homeomorphisms of a Manifold*, 1969 Math. USSR Sb. 8 287.

*Notes*: If $M$ is a metrisable topological manifold, then $Homeo(M)$ in the compact-open topology is a metrisable topological group. If $M$ is compact, then $Homeo(M)$ is locally contractible. If $M$ is noncompact, then $Homeo(M)$ may fail to be locally contractible (cf. [Kirby-Edwards](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970753?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)). The implication is that $Homeo(M)$ for compact $M$ may be an ANR. This is known to be true in dimensions $\leq 2$ (cf. [Yagasaki](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1107-8.pdf)) however it is an open problem for dimensions $\geq3$.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much the bunch of papers I am working through right now (though I didn't know the ref for the Yagasaki one).  I am mostly interested in what the contractibility of the homeomorphism group says about the dynamical properties of the space (esp. the plane, for me).  For example, just a childish observation, but if you have two homeomorphisms close to each other (so that they're in a contractible neighborhood of one-another) and two isotopies between them, then you should have a whole 'disc' of isotopies that average them, rather than just this loop.

Comment: Also, do you know the ref for when the homeomorphism group of the plane was shown to be path-connected?  Presumably it's much more elementary than going through the whole proof of the general case.

Comment: @JohnSamples I think an interpretation in those terms would be clearer in the Whitney topology (which actually has no connected open sets). I don't know how to say anything like that for the compact-open topology.

Comment: I actually believe that $Homeo(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has two path-components. These should coorespond to the orientation-preserving and orientation-reversing maps. I have a reference to the paper J. Roberts, *Concerning homeomorphisms of the plane onto itself*, Am. Math. Soc., **44**, but have not read it myself. I'd be grateful for a correction if I am mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, locally path-connected* as in the question!  Yes, it has two path components.

Comment: I'm guessing this one might do the job: M. Fort, *A proof that the group of all homeomorphisms of the plane onto itself is locally arcwise connected*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **1** (1950).

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!  You totally beasted this question <3

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you about interesting applications of this result. This is an important result if you care about classification of higher-dimensional topological manifolds, for instance, relating the TOP and PL categories. To see how , see section 8 in

*Rudyak, Yuli*, [**Piecewise linear structures on topological manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/9887), Hackensack, NJ: World Scientific (ISBN 978-981-4733-78-6/hbk; 978-981-4733-80-9/ebook). xxii, 106 p. (2016). [ZBL1356.57003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1356.57003).

A preliminary form, with some typos, you can find on the archive [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0105047.pdf).
I find this much more readable than Kirby and Siebenmann.

An example: Suppose that $f: T^n\to T^n$ is a homeomorphism homotopic to the identity. Then there is a finite covering map $M\to T^n$ such that $f$ lifts to a homeomorphism $M\to M$ which is isotopic to the identity. This, of course, uses only local path-connectivity of $Homeo(T^n)$. In order to get a sense of what local contractibility means, you should work with a family of homeomorphisms parameterized by your favorite compact manifold. Then local contractibility implies that (if the entire family moves all points just a tiny bit) then all these homeomorphisms can be **simultaneously isotopied** to the identity (as a family). For maps of the torus as above, this would mean that there is a finite covering such that the family of lifts is isotopic to $id_M$ **as a family.**

Comment: For the torus example, if all the homeos are close (all in a contractible neighborhood of a homeomorphism $f$ which is isotopic to the identity) we can still get the simultaneous isotopy, by first dragging them to $f$ and then to $id$, right?  Or can you not always pick a good nbhd+contraction that extends to a homeomorphism of $Aut(M)$?  Also, is it necessary that the family of homeos be a manifold?  It seems like as long as they're in a nbhd of $f$ we're good.  Still not sure what it means in the plane, I don't have a mental picture for "simultaneous isotopy" vs. "separate isotopies."

Comment: Maybe "simultaneous isotopy" compared to "separate isotopy" is about the time.  You can parameterize the time uniformly so that they all hit the identity at exactly $t=1$, and otherwise there are counterexamples for ENR's (maybe).

Comment: No, the parameter space need not be a manifold, but his example is sufficiently representative of the issue. Yes, since $Homeo(M)$ is a topological group the issue is about families close to $id$.

Comment: Hmm, I've encountered a technicality.  It seems like there are two definitions of "locally contractible"; the usual one, and the "geometric topologist's version": $X$ is locally contractible at $x$ if for every nbhd $U$ there's a nbhd $V \subset U$ such that $V$ deforms to $x$ in $U$.  So perhaps we can't say something quite this strong; I'm trying to understand the nuance of this and whether $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is locally connected in the strong sense (basis of contractible open sets).  I'm going to post an answer and maybe u can comment on it.

Comment: In my answer here I outlined something like your 'slowing stuff down' method for the case where there's no ambient isotopy to start:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390216/isotopies-fiber-bundles-and-selection-theorems/390951#390951  Actually not quite, but it might be possible to make $K_t$ as defined there grow very fast, while everything else happens 'slowly' enough to avoid winding and make the 'tree structure' I mentioned basically trivial to handle.  Please take a look at it and see if you know the right procedure!  There is also a PL idea, but I'm getting nowhere with that.

Comment: Like, instead of have $p_t(x)$ there be the 'constant' radial expansion, for each $t$ it will be $p_t$ at $\partial(K_t)$ but then rapidly slow off of it.  This should make the 'stuff happening outside of $K_t$' be 'small pieces' that 'look almost exactly like the original'.  Except they're just little pinky toes sticking off a huge disc, instead of huge tentacles obscuring the geometry.  I think this could finally be a method for a simple proof of these hard-ass theorems.

Answer (score 0):

So, someone pointed out to me that there's a complication.  Consider the following definition, which I'll call *semi-locally contractible*:

> $X$ is semi-locally contractible at the point $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $x$ such that $V$ deforms to $x$ in $U$.

It turns out that this is the definition of "locally contractible" that all of these papers from the 50's/60's/70's were using; I was under the impression that this definition was equivalent for these groups, but I think I was wrong.  It's sometimes referred to as the "geometric topologist's local contractibility."  So it may not be possible to say the following: A family of homeomorphisms sufficiently close to the identity (or some other homeomorphism $f$) can be simultaneously isotopied to the identity (or $f$ respectively).

However, it's not *a priori* obvious that $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2) = G$ *doesn't* also satisfy local contractibility in the strong sense, i.e. that every point has a local basis of contractible neighborhoods.  I'm wondering if the following collections of functions shed light on the issue, here.

We'll consider homeomorphisms close to the identity map of the plane.

First family:  Let $x_n = (0, \frac{1}{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and inductively define pairwise-disjoint discs $D_n$ centered at $x_n$ none containing $0$.  For visualization's sake, note that $D_n \rightarrow 0$.  For a fixed $n$, we will define a collection $\mathcal{F}_n$ of functions $f_k^n$ equal to the identity outside of $D_n$:

[image]

These functions pinch a pair of points closer and closer to the center of $D_n$.  It seems impossible to simultaneously isotopy all of them back to the identity.  Instead, we will need to take a smaller neighborhood in $G$ that doesn't contain the tail of any family $\mathcal{F}_n$.

Second family: Let $J$ be a circle in the plane around the center point $x$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the family of plane homeomorphisms such that $|f(j) - j| < \epsilon$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and all $j \in J$.  In particular, it contains the periodic, radial oscillations of the plane centered at $x$, i.e. for every straight line $L_\theta$ through $x$ it linearly maps $L_\theta$ to itself (orientation-preserving) by $f_\theta$.  If we parametrize the angles $L_\theta$ by $\pi$ we can let the derivative of $f_n^m$ along $L_\theta$ be $1+\frac{1}{n} \cdot sin(2m\theta)$ (for $n > 2$ to avoid some self-intersection complications).

Then for any $\epsilon$-nbhd of the identity in $G$, it will contain the family $\mathcal{F}_n = \lbrace f_n^m$ $|$ $m \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ for some $n$ but I think there is also no contraction of the whole family simultaneously.

Am I on the right track, or am I missing the idea here?

Comment: The terminology semi-locally contractible is already in usage. A space $X$ is *semi-locally contractible* if each point $x\in X$ has a neighbourhood $U$ for which the inclusion $U\subseteq X$ is inessential. A space which is homotopy equivalent to a locally-contractible space is semi-local contractible. eg. the cone on any space is semi-locally contractible.

Comment: I would really call the notion of local contractibility you introduce *local contractibility*, as it really is the standard notion. I would say that a space in which each point has a local base of contractible neighbourhoods is *strongly locally contractible* (this is not standard). Unfortunately this is not particularly useful: not many spaces which are strongly locally contractible (think manifolds and CW complexes). Any time you have a class of spaces which is generically locally contractible (thinks ANRs), they will rarely be strongly locally contractible.

Comment: The sentence "So it may not be possible to say the following: A family of homeomorphisms sufficiently close to the identity (or some other homeomorphism ) can be simultaneously isotopied to the identity (or  respectively)." does not reflect the reality. Local contractibility (in the sense of Chernavsky and Kirby-Siebenmann) gives you such simultaneous isotopy  and more. Tyrone is right, the notion of local contractibility they use **is** the standard one. Lastly, trying to construct a counter-example to their theorem is an interesting but futile exercise. (Also, $R^2$ is not compact.)

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks!  My def is how "locally" is used in most contexts.  A "local" topological property is almost always defined in the 'strong' sense.  If the term were useless because only manifolds et al. satisfy it, well, then the term "manifold" is useless too haha!  But you're right in that the couple books I have with "locally contractible" in the index define it as you have; however, Wikipedia currently has the 'strong' definition.  Someone should fix it, I might do it in a bit.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't understand your comment "Also, $R^2$ is not compact."  You say "Local contractibility gives you such simultaneous isotopy and more."  Ok, but if by "simultaneous isotopy" you mean the whole family contracts, then that's exactly what isn't the case.  I give you some family close to the identity, call it $U$, then you may need to take a smaller $V$ to contract.  I'm just trying to understand the obstruction and wondering how the behavior of the functions above fit into this whole picture.  Can you define "simultaneous isotopy", maybe that will end the confusion.

Comment: Or does the difference between the definitions only really refer to the functions through which the family is isotoped?  Maybe you are picturing that there is *some* $U, V$ as in the theorem, so esp. that $U$ contains a full $\epsilon$-nbhd of $id$.  Ok, I see that my idea would create a counterexample.  However, I'm still interested in what's going on with these examples, because it means my visualization of "simultaneous isotopy" is off.  It's hard to see how $F$ doesn't 'pick up' a discontinuous function when trying to rip the points back apart.

Comment: Basically, I'm asking this: Why is the space not locally contractible in the strong sense.  What's the proof?  Maybe the examples above show that you can't just take symmetric neighborhoods (symmetric wrt group inverse); if you tried to un-pinch the 'obvious way' with the inverse functions, THEN you'll have the problem?

Comment: I'm not good with infinite-dimensional stuff, so let me know if this is going nowhere fast, but could you try something like this?  Start with your $U$, then switch to $U'$ which is the symmetric closure of $U$ (still an open set).  You have some $V \subset U$ that deforms to a point in $U$ via deformation $d$, and thus in $U'$.  Now why wouldn't $tr(d(V))'$ be a bona-fide contractible nbhd within $U'$?  It seems like it would be at least in finite dimensions, *assuming* $id$ was fixed by $d$.  Is it not possible to require a single point be fixed under $d$?  If not, how to prove?