# Local Contractibility of Homogeneous, Locally Path-Connected Spaces

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups, continuum-theory

I was wondering about the following:

> Is it possible for a compact, metric, topological group to
> be locally path-connected but not locally contractible?

Here "locally contractible" means that every point has a local basis of contractible neighborhoods.  This is sometimes called "strongly locally contractible."

Originally I also asked specifically about the finite-dimensional case, but in the comments below it's pointed out that it's been solved: Such groups are Lie groups and thus locally contractible in the strong sense.  So, an example for groups where this fails would have to be infinite-dimensional. Especially, the Menger Cube is an example of a compact, metric, *homogeneous* space that's locally path-connected but not locally contractible; thus the full strength of "group" could well be necessary.

I'm asking in relation to this question, to give a bit of motivation.  This group isn't even locally compact, and it's known that there are manifolds whose homeomorphism groups aren't locally contractible even in a much weaker sense:

[Local Contractibility of Homeomorphism Group of $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075662/local-contractibility-of-homeomorphism-group-of-mathbbrn)

Comment: Locally compact (although that requirement may not be even needed), Hausdorff, locally path-connected topological group of finite topological dimension is a Lie group (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385829/are-locally-compact-hausdorff-locally-path-connected-topological-groups-locall ). Thus locally contractible.

Comment: Ok, nice!  So the Menger Cube is definitely not a topological group.  I'll adjust the question.

Comment: Infinite dimensional case is interesting. My intuition tells me that things often go wrong there. But I have no counterexample yet.

Comment: Yeah, I expect it to be false.  Diffeomorphism group of the complement of some wild set, something like that maybe.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864114004404 possibly relevant paper (also a reference for the result in freakish's comment). In fact it shows you can even drop the locally compact. Unfortunately they don't talk about local contractibility.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll go through it in the next day or two!

Comment: Please, change the title question since in the present for it is totally misleading.

Comment: That would be unfair to Freakish!  Perhaps if someone answers the general version . . . ;D

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and changed it since I'm still curious.  A good excuse to bump it.

Comment: The "torus" $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^\mathbf{N}$ is a compact metrizable group that is locally path-connected but not locally contractible.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice and digestible example!  Thanks!  It seems that it's not even locally contractible in the weak sense.